# Blocked requests by default to https self signed backend

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, backend

On my staging server I am connecting to self-signed https api backend. And by default requests can't be made, because browser treat backend as danger.

I have to open backend url in browser

`https://my-api-backend.elasticbeanstalk.com`

`my-api-backend.elasticbeanstalk.com:8443 uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. The certificate is not valid for the name my-api-backend.elasticbeanstalk.com. Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER`

After manually confirm that is secure it works. It is fine for me to do this, but not for managers etc. Another thing I was thinking about blocking backend access from outside and allow access only from frontend.

Is there any solution to this problem other than buying domain a sign it properly?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a staging environment it should reflect a production environment so you should use a real domain signed correctly.

Certificates are free through AWS ACM or LetsEncrypt.

Why not use a sub domain like staging.domain.com, it would be free as well. Otherwise domains are cheap and it shouldn't be worth the hassle.

Comment: In fact that domain is not bought yet and I don't want to wait for it. But still, it seems to be best option and eventually I will wait for it